# Database / application design for very flexible application

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, application-design

I'm having difficulty getting my head around the logic behind an application I'm working on. I am writing it in PHP with a MySQL DB. Basically the logic is based around the fact that everything has attributes - for example a car has a colour, 4 doors, a roof, an engine and so on. Each part then has its own attributes and might be made of smaller parts. Essentially each part has its own parts and each attribute has its own attributes.

I am using similar logic for an application whereby you have users, roles & rights. Each role may only be able to see certain roles but this is defined using rights assigned to each role. Each object type (user, role, right) has its own attributes. One such attribute for user would be roles. For roles it would be rights. Then they have their own fields (other attributes) such as name, description etc.. Name has an attribute of field type = text, description = longtext / textarea, etc. and then they both have their own description, placeholder, whether or not they are directly editable or automatic (on creation / update of an object - such as inserteddate or updateddate). Then you need a UI to define the fields - essentially you need to know what attributes a field has in order to define the UI to create or edit a field - which came first, the chicken or the egg? How / where do you define the markup for the UI if all objects are stored in the database? Can you even go this deep or will it cause an infinite loop?

Has anyone ever built a system like this before? It just seems that I keep getting to a point where I'm abstracting everything out too far, confusing myself and taking a break and then I just repeat this process over and over. Not sure if I should continue going down this road or if I should just define everything solidly in the DB (such as a users table with name, description etc. columns and a link between user and role and role and right). Any opinions would be welcome.

PS I have tried using WordPress for this but it is not suited to this project due to, in my experience, WP not being flexible enough to alter the users list or form to the extent that we would like.

Comment: Please can people NOT vote to close unless they're willing to state a reason?!? I am simply asking for advice - it may not be a question with a single correct answer but it is perfectly valid and within the StackOverflow rules...

Comment: See JSON.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as infinite flexibility. If there was, entire Internet could be served by a single app with slightly different configurations :)

Mysql is a relational database. Relational databases aren't very flexible by nature. Tables consist of rows and each row has fixed amount of columns and represent an entity with fixed amount of properties. If that doesn't fit your needs, you might look into object databases or graph databases.

Regarding UI, Symfony Form component can generate forms based on user defined "types" and it works recursively by nature: each type can be a "simple" input type like a text input, checkbox etc, or "compound" input, which will render a child form, which can in turn have other nested child forms etc. It is quite a complex component though and once you start getting deeper into complex validation logic... you will start wondering why you decided to go this "flexible" way in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Karolis. I have just looked into it briefly and it looks similar to what I have so far (although mine is so much more basic). I decided to think over this whilst watching some TV and may have come up with a happy medium where only fields are hardcoded but the list of fields against the field object type is database driven. I would have to define the markup for the form elements but that's it. I will have a crack at it this way for the next 24 hours and, if I find myself no further forward, I will look further into Symfony. Thank you for the warning, btw :)